# The specified language targets for MonoAndroid90 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'MonoAndroid'

Tags: xamarin.forms

When trying to build an older Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2019, I get the following error:

```
The specified language targets for MonoAndroid90 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'MonoAndroid'. Missing: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets'    MediaManager    C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.24\Build\LanguageTargets\CheckMissing.targets   36
```

I have the following SDK items installed.

[image: Installed SDKs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the first line of the csproj file from

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras">
```

to the line below

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/3.0.22">
```

3.0.22 was the current version of the [MSBuild.Sdk.Extras Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/).

I also restarted VS, cleaned the project, etc. along the way.

Comment: Hi, glad solved! Remember to mark it when you can, it will help others who have the same problems.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me too.  I was fretting using the newer version of sdk.extras because it had issues running in linux for me, but im not compiling this project on linux atm so should be good for now :)